# Given 3 sorted arrays A, B, C and number S, find i, j, k such that A[i] + B[j] + C[k] = S

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I've just found out how to solve this in `O(n^2 log n)` time (assuming each array has the same length):

```
for each A[i]:
  for each B[j]:
    if A[i] + B[j] + C.binarySearch(S - A[i] - B[j]) == S:
       return (i, j, k)
```

Is there any way to solve this in `O(n^2)` time or to improve the above algorithm?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/

Comment: @KamleshArya, it's the version with one array, but I have the version with 3 arrays.

Comment: If I am right, the algorithm pointed by @Kamlesh Arya does not depend on the fact that all elements belong to the same array but just on the fact that the values are sorted. You should be able to adapt easily.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you have ain't bad. Relative to `n^2`, `log(n)` grows so slowly that it can practically be considered a constant. For example, for `n = 1000000`, `n^2 = 1000000000000` and `log(n) = 20`. Once `n` becomes large enough for `log(n)` to have any significant influence, `n^2` will already be so big that the result cannot be computed anyway.

A solution, inspired by @YvesDaoust, though I'm not sure if it's exactly the same:

- For every `A[i]`, calculate the remainder `R = S - A[i]` which should be a combination of some `B[j]` and `C[k]`;
- Let `j = 0` and `k = |C|-1` (the last index in `C`);
- If `B[j] + C[k] < R`, increase `j`;
- If `B[j] + C[k] > R`, decrease `k`;
- Repeat the two previous steps until `B[j] + C[k] = R` or `j >= |B|` or `k < 0`

I suggest not to complicate the algorithm too much with micro-optimizations. For any reasonably small set of numbers and it will be fast enough. If the arrays become too large for this approach, your problem would make a good candidate for Machine Learning approaches such as Hill Climbing.

Answer (score 0):

The `O(N²)` solution is very simple.

First consider the case of two arrays, finding `A[i] + B[j] = S'`.

This can be rewritten as `A[i] = S' - B[j] = B'[j]`: you need to find equal values in two sorted arrays. This is readily done in linear time with a merging process. (You can explicitly compute the array `B'` but this is unnecessary, just do it on the fly: instead of fetching `B'[j]`, get `S' - B[NB-1-j]`).

Having established this procedure, it suffices to use it for all elements of `C`, in search of `S - C[k]`.

Here is Python code that does that and reports all solutions. (It has been rewritten to be compact and symmetric.)

```
for k in range(NC):
    # Find S - C[k] in top-to-tail merged A and B
    i, j= 0, NB - 1
    while i < NA and 0 <= j:
        if A[i] + B[j] + C[k] < S:
            # Move forward A
            i+= 1
        elif A[i] + B[j] + C[k] > S:
            # Move back B
            j-= 1
        else:
            # Found
            print A[i] + B[j] + C[k], "=", A[i], "+", B[j], "+", C[k]
            i+= 1; j-= 1
```

Execution with

```
A= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; NA= len(A)
B= [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]; NB= len(B)
C= [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]; NC= len(C)

S= 15
```

gives

```
15 = 3 + 11 + 1
15 = 7 + 7 + 1
15 = 3 + 11 + 1
15 = 7 + 7 + 1
15 = 2 + 11 + 2
15 = 6 + 7 + 2
15 = 1 + 11 + 3
15 = 5 + 7 + 3
15 = 7 + 5 + 3
15 = 3 + 7 + 5
15 = 5 + 5 + 5
15 = 7 + 3 + 5
15 = 1 + 7 + 7
15 = 3 + 5 + 7
15 = 5 + 3 + 7
15 = 6 + 2 + 7
```

Comment: It is worth to note that for this problem, thinking in terms of dichotomic search makes it harder!

Answer (score 0):

if the arrays are of non-negatives
 * you can trim all 3 arrays to at S => `A[n] > S`
 * similarly, dont bother checking array C if A[aIdx] + B[bIdx] > S

Answer (score 0):

prepare:

- sort each array ascending `+O(N.log(n))`
- implement binary search on each array `?O(log(N))`

compute:

```
i=bin_search(smallest i that A[i]+B[0]+C[0]>=S); for (;i<Na;i++) { if (A[i]+B[0]+C[0]>S) break;
 j=bin_search(smallest j that A[i]+B[j]+C[0]>=S); for (;j<Nb;j++) { if (A[i]+B[j]+C[0]>S) break;
  ss=S-A[i]-B[j];
  if (ss<0) break;
  k=bin_search(ss);
  if (k found) return; // found solution is: i,j,k
  }
 }
```

if I see it right and: `N=max(Na,Nb,Nc)`, `M=max(valid intervals A,B,C)` ... `M<=N`

- it is `(3*N.log(N)+log(N)+M*log(N)*M*log(N)) -> O((M^2)*log(N))`
- the j binary search can be called just once and then iterate +1 if needed
- **the complexity is the same but the N has changed**
- for average conditions is this much much faster because `M<<N`